# HTTP2 causes more requests/longer load time?

Tags: http, https, windows-10, http2, iis-10

I am starting to look into HTTP/2, running tests on Windows 10/IIS 10. From what I understand HTTP/2 is enabled there by default for secure connections. Yet when I am browsing a local site from Chrome 67.0.3396.99 - HTTP/2 seems slower, issuing more requests.

HTTP connection:
[image: HTTP connection]

HTTPS connection:
[image: HTTPS connection]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to even hazard a guess. Could be any number of things completely unrelated to HTTP/2 or even HTTPS. Maybe the HTTPS site is a completely different site to the HTTP site?

Comment: @BarryPollard it's my local IIS 10 server on my Windows 10 dev laptop. Same site just different binding.

Comment: Your tests can simply be invalid, as HTTP/2 does not guarantee performance boost on HTTP 1.1 optimized sites. Many HTTP 1.1 specific optimization tips simply make the sites much slower on HTTP/2. There are too many articles/resources around the internet on such, like https://blogs.akamai.com/2016/06/where-is-my-http2-performance.html So get yourself started with HTTP/2 and then you can figure out. Too broad a question at this moment.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, this adds some useful information. Will dig deeper. But I can say that this test site of mine doesn't do any /1 optimizations (JS/CSS bundling, image spriting etc.) All pages and images are served from the same domain. The only thing - the site is on localhost, local to the browser, so "superfast" connection. Maybe I'll try throttling it.

Comment: HTTP/1 performance optimisations do not slow down a site when run under HTTP:2 - they just may not be as necessary! However I agree that localhost will unlikely show a difference between the two protocols. But you haven’t even shown if it’s using HTTP/2! Add the protocol column to the network tab and confirm that. HTTPS will add some extra connection setup time which might explain the small increase. However the biggest question is why you have 8 extra resources under HTTPS? Only you can answer that since you have given us no details.

Comment: @BarryPollard didn't know I can display protocol, thanks. For HTTPS connection it does shows as H2, And I have no idea why it issues more requests - it's the same site (basic ASP.NET Webforms site) just on different bindings

Comment: Then it's a matter of going through all the requests in th Network tab to find what's different. Probably easier going through each tab and seeing if number of JS scripts are the same, if number of CSS stylesheets are the same...etc.

Comment: @BarryPollard thank you so much for your help, I figured it out. There were several invalid JS and CSS references in pages of the site, so browser tried to get them over H2, failed and then tried again over HTTP/1.1 - hence more requests. When I fixed that - I do see faster loading times - even on localhost. Could you please post your advice as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows 8 additional requests being loaded over HTTPS so you are not comparing like for like. Investigate what those are and you'll likely have your answer.

Additionally while the latest version of IIS uses HTTP/2 by default you are better adding the protocol column to the network tab to confirm if this is being used. That way you know whether you are comparing HTTP to HTTPS or HTTP to HTTP/2 (over HTTPS).

HTTP/2 is primarily faster over high latency connections so you may not notice much difference over low latency connections (e.g. if testing with localhost) but it shouldn't really be any slower because of this (except for perhaps a small additional initial connection SSL/TLS negotiation time for HTTPS).